# can someone tell me why this error appears to me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The error :

```
React Hook "useState" is called in function "createFlight" that is  
neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.  
React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react- 
hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

My code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react'




function createFlight(){
    const [flight, setflight] = useState({flightNumber: "", departureTime: "", arrivalTime: "", departureDate: "", arrivalDate: "", cabin: "", economySeatsAvailable: "", businessSeatsAvailable: "", airport: "", from: "", to: "" });
    
}

export default createFlight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your component to start with an uppercase (as the error states).

```
function CreateFlight(){
```

If instead it is supposed to be a custom hook you need to name it prepending `use` in the name. Such as `useCreateFlight`

Answer (score 0):

React hooks can only be called in React components or other React hooks.

React components have to be upper-case, like so

```
function CreateFlight(){
    const [flight, setflight] = useState();
}
```

They can then be rendered like so

```
<CreateFlight />
```

React hooks are functions that bind behaviour into a component. They have to be named "use..." like, "useFlight" or something.